# BlobStore upload URL works, but returns 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, blobstore

I am attempting to upload pictures to google Blobstore using purely javascript. I have a REST api that I query to get the upload url. I grab the upload url and post using the following code:

```
<form id="newmemberAccount" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fileUpload" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Upload Picture</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"/>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" ng-click="uploadPicture()" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Submit</button>
```

I then get the information by the following code in my Angular controller:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
        newprofileImage = new FormData();
        //Take the first selected file
        newprofileImage.append("file", files[0]);
    }


$scope.uploadPicture = function(){

        console.log(newprofileImage);
        $http.post($scope.url, newprofileImage, {
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            })
        .success(function(data){
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log("failure");
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

When I run the post request, I get a 404 response but I can see the image has uploaded to the blob in the app engine console. So I'm really confused as to what I'm doing wrong. I need to get the response so I can find where the image is being hosted. Below I will post what the http request sends, taken from my chrome console.
Request Headers:

```
host:greek-app.appspot.com
:method:POST
:path:/_ah/upload/AMmfu6ZMBz-K8oR9rk5OWfcp2Q0RO2xAJgAgAzCkECtoc0X7yR2rFkRVxp6zk_hsEbBfbxVYMO9019P34-3NJpMH0j40pnaOrhbvK8aBtIVG6nV3IBiNg11RkvWxib7R91AKILGOI5Mg/ALBNUaYAAAAAU4YdODoOR0AThPmQmDt8Xzv7cpEY4H33/
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
cache-control:no-cache
content-length:156171
content-type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryZtJNWWPvaj71mTbg
cookie:USER_NAME=derek.wene; TOKEN=92576e74-f3dc-4174-9d70-e1bd9fffb7c0
origin:https://greek-app.appspot.com
pragma:no-cache
referer:https://greek-app.appspot.com/
```

Request Payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZtJNWWPvaj71mTbg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";
filename="10338463_10202806339897092_340454719367107135_o.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryZtJNWWPvaj71mTbg--
```

Comment: It sounds like the problem is actually (or mostly) on the server-side. If you're seeing the desired result there yet still getting a 404 back, then it seems like it's the response that is misconfigured (ie server should respond with something other than a 404).

Comment: 1) Yes, did you check the handler after the redirect. 2) You can also send and receive blobs without using an upload_url to find out where the problem is.

Comment: I see what you are saying. How can I use a handler with python if I am using angular to send the post request? I have the UploadHandler implemented similarly to what is shown in the demo website here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Complete_sample_application

I want to use angular to send the post, but use the UploadHandler written in python.